# как заставить бота отвечать на неизвестную команду?

Tags: python, aiogram

хочу чтобы бот отвечал на команду которой нету в меню команд текстом:
`Упс, похоже что это неизвестная команда!\nСписок команд вы можете посмотреть в меню`

Answer (score 0):

Вот так:

```
@dp.message_handler()
async def info(message: types.Message):
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Упс, похоже что это неизвестная команда!\nСписок команд вы можете посмотреть в меню')
```

Бот будет отвечать данным текстом на любое сообщение, если в нем не распознается команда. Этот хэндлер должен располагаться под всеми остальными хэндлерами, иначе команды из них будут обработаны данным хэндлером.